# What's wrong with logging into peer network -hyperledger fabric (eca.user)?

Tags: git, bash, vagrant, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

can anyone help me out with this? I'm not sure what's wrong with the login of the peer network(hyperledger fabric).

I followed their steps in 
`http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Setup/Chaincode-setup/` , under the note on security functionality. I tried as what's stated. I did vagrant ssh, 
`cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer` and followed by

```
peer network login admin
```

(a default file of membersrvc.yaml).

I did try out other username and password, but none of it worked as it shown error. To my understanding, when it shows errors, it would mean that the user and password are incorrect. However, i copied and pasted the user and password and it didnt work. May i know what's wrong with the user and password for logging into peer network (hyperledger fabric- using of git bash)?

The user and passwords(eca.user- showing the user and password) will be shown in the following (membersrvc.yaml) :

```
    eca:


              # This hierarchy is used to create the Pre-key tree, affiliations is the top of this hierarchy, 'banks_and_institutions' is used to create the key associated to auditors of both banks and
                # institu

tions, 'banks' is used to create a key associated to auditors of banks, 'bank_a' is used to create a key associated to auditors of bank_a, etc.
            affiliations:
               banks_and_institutions:
                  banks:
                      - bank_a
                      - bank_b
                      - bank_c
                  institutions:
                      - institution_a
            users:
                    #
                    # The fields of each user are as follows:
                    #    <EnrollmentID>: <system_role (1:client, 2: peer, 4: validator, 8: auditor)> <EnrollmentPWD> <Affiliation> <Affiliation_Role> <JSON_Metadata>
                    #
                    # The optional JSON_Metadata field is of the following format:
                    #   { "registrar": { "roles": <array-of-role-names>, "delegateRoles": <array-of-role-names> } }
                    # The 'registrar' section is used to control access to registration of new users directly via the ECAA.RegisterUser GRPC call.
                    # (See the 'fabric/membersrvc/protos/ca.proto' file for the definition of ECAA.RegisterUser.)
                    # Note that this also controls who can register users via the client SDK.
                    #
                    # Only users with a 'registrar' section may be a registrar to register other users.  In particular,
                    # 1) the "roles" field specifies which member roles may be registered by this user, and
                    # 2) the "delegateRoles" field specifies which member roles may become the "roles" field of registered users.
                    # The valid role names are "client", "peer", "validator", and "auditor".
                    #
                    # Example1:
                    #    The 'admin' user below can register clients, peers, validators, or auditors; furthermore, the 'admin' user can register other
                    #    users who can then register clients only.
                    #
                    # Example2:
                    #    The 'WebAppAdmin' user below can register clients only, but none of the users registered by this user can register other users.
                    #
                    admin: 1 Xurw3yU9zI0l institution_a '{"registrar":{"roles":["client","peer","validator","auditor"],"delegateRoles":["client"]}}'
                    WebAppAdmin: 1 DJY27pEnl16d institution_a '{"registrar":{"roles":["client"]}}'
                    lukas: 1 NPKYL39uKbkj bank_a
                    system_chaincode_invoker: 1 DRJ20pEql15a institution_a
                    diego: 1 DRJ23pEQl16a institution_a
                    jim: 1 6avZQLwcUe9b bank_a
                    binhn: 1 7avZQLwcUe9q institution_a
                    testing: 1 test123 institution_a

                    # Users for asset transfer with roles test located at
                    # sdk/node/test/unit/asset-mgmt-with-roles.js
                    alice: 1 CMS10pEQlB16 bank_a
                    bob: 1 NOE63pEQbL25 bank_a
                    assigner: 1 Tc43PeqBl11 bank_a

                    vp: 4 f3489fy98ghfAD

                    test_vp0: 4 MwYpmSRjupbT
                    test_vp1: 4 5wgHK9qqYaPy
                    test_vp2: 4 vQelbRvja7cJ
                    test_vp3: 4 9LKqKH5peurL
                    test_vp4: 4 Pqh90CEW5juZ
                    test_vp5: 4 FfdvDkAdY81P
                    test_vp6: 4 QiXJgHyV4t7A
                    test_vp7: 4 twoKZouEyLyB
                    test_vp8: 4 BxP7QNh778gI
                    test_vp9: 4 wu3F1EwJWHvQ

    # Uncomment this section to activate devnet setup as specficied in
    # devnet-setup.md
    #
    #               vp0: 4 vp0_secret
    #               vp1: 4 vp1_secret

                    test_user0: 1 MS9qrN8hFjlE bank_a
                    test_user1: 1 jGlNl6ImkuDo institution_a
                    test_user2: 1 zMflqOKezFiA bank_c
                    test_user3: 1 vWdLCE00vJy0 bank_a
                    test_user4: 1 4nXSrfoYGFCP institution_a
                    test_user5: 1 yg5DVhm0er1z bank_b
                    test_user6: 1 b7pmSxzKNFiw bank_a
                    test_user7: 1 YsWZD4qQmYxo institution_a
                    test_user8: 1 W8G0usrU7jRk bank_a
                    test_user9: 1 H80SiB5ODKKQ institution_a

                    test_nvp0: 2 iywrPBDEPl0K bank_a
                    test_nvp1: 2 DcYXuRSocuqd institution_a
                    test_nvp2: 2 flpChShlY7xt bank_c
                    test_nvp3: 2 jeruawMomclo bank_a
                    test_nvp4: 2 RMYVxSZCk370 institution_a
                    test_nvp5: 2 XHYVCIJGZGK7 bank_b
                    test_nvp6: 2 4cIn63j8ahYp bank_a
                    test_nvp7: 2 E7FAJUtWVn2h institution_a
                    test_nvp8: 2 LJu8DkUilBEH bank_a
                    test_nvp9: 2 VlEsBsiyXSjw institution_a
```

The following codes will be what i key into git bash to log into peer network(hyperledger fabric) :

```
vagrant@hyperledger-devenv:v0.0.11-c6e56d6:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer$ peer network login admin

Enter password for user 'admin': Xurw3yU9zI0l
```

The following will be the errors after i input the password:

```
2016/09/14 07:05:33 grpc: addrConn.resetTransport failed to create client transport: connection error: desc = "transport: dial tcp 0.0.0.0:7051: getsockopt: connection refused"; Reconnecting to {"0.0.0.0:7051" <nil>}
2016/09/14 07:05:35 grpc: addrConn.resetTransport failed to create client transport: connection error: desc = "transport: dial tcp 0.0.0.0:7051: getsockopt: connection refused"; Reconnecting to {"0.0.0.0:7051" <nil>}
2016/09/14 07:05:35 grpc: addrConn.resetTransport failed to create client transport: connection error: desc = "transport: dial tcp 0.0.0.0:7051: getsockopt: connection refused"; Reconnecting to {"0.0.0.0:7051" <nil>}
Error: Error trying to connect to local peer: grpc: timed out when dialing
Usage:
  peer network login <username> [flags]

Flags:
  -p, --password string   The password for user. You will be requested to enter the password if this flag is not specified.

Global Flags:
      --logging-level string       Default logging level and overrides, see core.yaml for full syntax
      --test.coverprofile string   Done (default "coverage.cov")
  -v, --version                    Display current version of fabric peer server

vagrant@hyperledger-devenv:v0.0.11-c6e56d6:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer$
```

Updated:
Yes, i am able to achieve something similar like this

```
06:04:34.617 [crypto] RegisterClient -> INFO 017 Registering client [admin] with                               name [admin]...
06:04:34.737 [crypto] Info -> INFO 018 [client.admin]  Register crypto engine...
06:04:34.738 [crypto] Info -> INFO 019 [client.admin]  Register crypto engine...                              done.
06:04:34.739 [crypto] RegisterClient -> INFO 01a Registering client [admin] with                               name [admin]...done!
```

But, may i know why can I only log in for just once? For instance, if i want to log into admin again, it won't prompt for password and it will have something like this

```
vagrant@hyperledger-devenv:v0.0.11-087d2ea:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer$ peer network login admin
vagrant@hyperledger-devenv:v0.0.11-087d2ea:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer$
```

Comment: did you initiate the peer process by `peer node start` first in a separate terminal window ?

Comment: I'm sorry. I dont get you. Is there any example or website that i can refer to?

Comment: the link that you have posted above, please read **Running the validating peer** part carefully. It should be running in a separate terminal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for your error,

```
2016/09/14 07:05:33 grpc: addrConn.resetTransport failed to create client transport: connection error: desc = "transport: dial tcp 0.0.0.0:7051: getsockopt: connection refused"; Reconnecting to {"0.0.0.0:7051" <nil>}
```

is that there is no `peer` running on `0.0.0.0:7051`.

here is what you should do,

from your fabric directory run `membersrvc` first (read [this](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/docs/Setup/ca-setup.md#Operating-the-CA) on how to setup CA),
then in a separate terminal, run the following command to initiate a `peer` process,

```
CORE_SECURITY_ENABLED=true CORE_SECURITY_PRIVACY=true peer node start --peer-chaincodedev
```

notice that I am running it in `dev` mode.

open another terminal and run the following,

```
peer network login lukas
```

enter (or paste) password when prompted.

In the second window (where you have initiated the peer), you will see the following output,

```
08:48:18.978 [crypto] RegisterClient -> INFO 01b Registering client [lukas] with name [lukas]...
08:48:19.179 [crypto] Info -> INFO 01c [client.lukas]  Register crypto engine...
08:48:19.181 [crypto] Info -> INFO 01d [client.lukas]  Register crypto engine...done.
08:48:19.183 [crypto] RegisterClient -> INFO 01e Registering client [lukas] with name [lukas]...done!
```

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thanks for helping! I am able to get something similar to yours but, i can only log in to admin for once. For instance, if i log into lukas, i can't log into lukas again. May i know why this happen? I have shown the updated version above. @Sufiyan Ghori

Answer (score 2):

An answer to the second part of question “why can I only log in for just once?” is following:

User can have only one Enrolment certificate. Membership service will generate unique Enrolment certificate at first user’s login to the network. 
As soon as Enrolment certificate is issued, membership service will “disable” user’s account by overriding Enrolment password.

In your example, when you send ‘login’ command to the same peer, this peer will check that user is registered and will not send any requests to Membership service.

In configuration with multiple peers, user can login to one of them only. Second attempt to login via another peer will lead to:

```
Error: Error on client login: roc error: code = 2 desc = Identity or token does not match.
```